# Eclipse not showing the 'USB Driver package'

Tags: android, eclipse

I just downloaded and installed the latest version of Eclipse and the Android SDK and ADT yesterday, July 15, 2011.

But when I open up Eclipse, and go to the menu item Window->Android SDK and AVD manager and select  'Available Packages,' there is no "USB Driver Package" installed and I'm on Windows Vista and was led to expect a USB package to be there so that I could install it.

I apparently got the Eclipse 'Indigo' release; and the Version: 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431  of the ADT

The 'Android Development' book says I need the USB Driver package to be able to debug on an actual Android device, as opposed to debugging using the emulator.

Why isn't the USB Driver Package showing up?

Comment: The device you are using must have usb driver package . May be given along a CD. Install them if you find.  Also check that your device setting is enabled for Application Development. Go on to the setting ->Application -> Development ..  Check all the check boxes found related

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Eclipse Galileo and version 3.2 of Android SDK and AVD Manager.  I had the same problem as yourself (USB Driver Package was not in the Available Packages)- I went to "Installed Packages" and pressed the 'Update All' button at the bottom of the window. The Choose Packages to Install window appeared with Google USB Driver package so I was able to accept the license and install no problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: I also had the same problem, opening the SDK manager via eclipse gave me the option to download USB Driver.  I also had to bypass our proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed your device USB driver on the system you are trying this? If not try with that.

Comment: I haven't installed my HTC EVO's USB driver on my laptop, but the install instructions I have for the Android SDK and AVD Manager shows that the "Usb Driver package" should automatically appear under 'Available Packages->Android Repository' -- and 'Usb Driver package' is simply not there.  My understanding is this 'Usb Driver package' is a generic package that works with a device-specific driver you supply prior to debugging on your Android phone.

Comment: Just checking, do you see it present under the "Installed Packages"?